# Python Strange Issues with Ghost.py

Tags: python, import, ghost.py

Hello stackoverflow community once again.  I have yet another question.

Recently, I've found a python library that looked rather useful to me for a recent project by the name of Ghost.py.  This library is a net library.

The issue I'm having is a rather strange error.  Google is turning up nothing relevant.

```
from .ghost import Ghost
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

As you can see, it's a rather odd error.  Any help on solving this error is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "_net library_"? Did you mean that you are using IronPython and this is a .Net library? Also, could you share that library? Also, why the relative import? Shouldn't `from ghost import Ghost` be enough? Or maybe it is an error within that library?

Comment: By net library, I mean a library for running JavaScript and HTTP statement.  It could be an error within that library, but I haven't managed to find another library of its type that can use JavaScript on web-pages.

Comment: I got the same error with `pip install ghost.py`. When I installed manually using the zip from github, everything worked great. If you haven't got it working already, give that a try.

Answer (score 3):

+1 for Babby Boss as his/her solution will work however I was lazy and I came here when I also had the issue and my problem was fixed by by me uninstalling `Ghost` which I had installed like the OP using pip and instead installing `Ghost.py`

Note that `Ghost` and `Ghost.py` are not the same, and using pip to install `Ghost` will cause an error if, like me, you wanted `Ghost.py`

So simple fix =
`pip2 uninstall Ghost` (wait for this to complete)
`pip2 install Ghost.py`

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra `.` in front of ghost.  I don't think you need it:

```
from ghost import Ghost
```

Comment: It depends on where it is located (if this line is in external library, then the issue is not OP's error seemingly).

Comment: Without it I am granted with another error, hence why I put it there in the first place.  It was suggested to do so in an old thread I found about error number one.  Removing it gives me this error:ImportError: cannot import name Ghost

Comment: How did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from writing correct code like `from ghost import Ghost`, you may like to follow steps outlined below.

Download `ghost.py` master file from https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py/archive/master.zip

Unzip contents of `master.zip` to `C:\ghost-master` folder

If you carefully watch the folder structure then you find that `ghost\__init__.py` file has following content.

```
from .ghost import Ghost, Error, TimeoutError
from .test import GhostTestCase
```

While `ghost\ext\__init__.py` is of 0 KB

In this case, when you run following command to build the package.

```
C:\<path_to_Python_folder>\python.exe setup.py build
```

you see that apart from other lines, following line also appears.

```
copying ghost\ext\__init__.py -> build\lib\ghost\ext
```

It means that `__init__.py` of 0 KB size is being copied as `build\lib\ghost\ext\__init__.py`

Therefore, even though installing ghost.py with following command does not produce any error, you face `ImportError: cannot import name Ghost`.

```
C:\<path_to_Python_folder>\python.exe setup.py install
```

So, to solve the problem, before building the package overwrite `__init__.py` file

```
C:\ghost-master>copy ghost\__init__.py ghost\ext\
```

Now issue following commands.

```
C:\<path_to_Python_folder>\python.exe setup.py build
C:\<path_to_Python_folder>\python.exe setup.py install
```

Now you will not see `ImportError: cannot import name Ghost`

I have tested above solution with Python 2.7.6